# É possível selecionar uma coluna da tabela sem informar o nome dela em SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Então, estava pesquisando mas não encontrei nada a respeito, mas preciso tipo selecionar a primeira e segunda coluna da tabela, sem saber quais são elas. Meu código é esse:

```
<?php $preparaNormalizacao=$con->prepare("SELECT * FROM ".$tabelaExterna." INNER JOIN ".$tabelaNormalizacao." ON ".$tabelaNormalizacao.".".$cTEnormaliza."=".$tabelaExterna.".".$cTEexterna);?>
```

Preciso fazer algo desse tipo aqui, onde eu não sei os nomes Coluna1 e Coluna2:

```
<?php $preparaNormalizacao=$con->prepare("SELECT Coluna1,Coluna2 FROM ".$tabelaExterna." INNER JOIN ".$tabelaNormalizacao." ON ".$tabelaNormalizacao.".".$cTEnormaliza."=".$tabelaExterna.".".$cTEexterna);?>
```

É possível? Agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode fazer assim:

1) Primeiro construi uma query dinamica

```
SELECT 
   CONCAT('SELECT ', GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME), ' FROM test') 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE() AND TABLE_NAME = 'test' 
    ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION DESC 
    LIMIT 10
) AS ord_desc 
ORDER BY ord_desc.ORDINAL_POSITION
```

O resultado será algo assim:

```
SELECT date,title FROM test
```

Depois com o resultado no php abre uma nova conexao do SQL anterior

Comment: Opa Valeu, no caso só precisei ajustar o LIMIT para iniciar e terminar na posição que eu quero.